# Efficient method to return first match between two arrays

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking to to categorize bank transactions using R (I'm most familiar with the dplyr package). I have two data frames:

- `trans_data`: holds the transaction data (importantly a transaction # and description)
- `trans_categories`: holds match criteria and category names

I'm looking to add a column to `trans_data` that includes the first item in `trans_categories` that fits the criteria.

For example, given the following data frames:

```
trans_data = data.frame(
   "number" = c("abc123", "def456", "ghi789"), 
   "description" = c("transfer to x000", "transfer to x000", "transfer to x111"), 
   "number_description" = paste0(number, "-", description)   #sloppy here, but intended to concatenate prior two columns
)

trans_categories = data.frame(
   "criteria" = c("abc123", "transfer to x000", "transfer"), 
   "category" = c("expense reimbursement", "transfer to x000", "transfer")
)
```

I'd like to append a column to `trans_data` that returns `c("expense reimbursement", "transfer to x000", "transfer")`. In other words, based on the `number_description` column in `trans_data`, we find the first instance where `trans_categories$criteria` matches, and return the corresponding value in `trans_categories$category`.

I can do this with some sort of a loop that breaks when a match is found, but I assume that this is inelegant / slow for large data frames.

Comment: In your example, the values in `trans_data$number_description` do not match anything in `trans_categories$criteria`. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @z.lin : I’m looking for the first entry that includes a substring match. Eg “abc123” would return a true for “abc” and “abc123” but not “abc1234”